# IBM Worklight - $("#pagePort").load() not working in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using  `$("#pagePort").load()` for navigating between pages in my app, and it's working in Android (both emulator & device) perfectly.

However, my app can't change its page when i tried to run it from Windows Phone 8's emulator.

Comment: Please state your Worklight version as well as jQuery Mobile version.

Comment: Is this question resolved? Please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following in order to make the changePage functionality work in Windows Phone 8. I suspect this change will make many things "suddenly" work as well.

This change is supposed to be part of the next jQuery Mobile release at some point in time...
Please  try it:

open jquery.mobile-1.x.x.js and refactor the code as follows:

```
-        var uri = url ? this.parseUrl( url ) : location,
-        hash = this.parseUrl( url || location.href ).hash;
+        var uri = this.parseUrl( url || location.href ),
+        hash = uri.hash;
```

and:

```
-        return uri.protocol + "//" + uri.host + uri.pathname + uri.search + hash;
+        return uri.protocol + uri.doubleSlash + uri.host + uri.pathname + uri.search + hash;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where can i find the jquery mobile .js? I think i dont use one...

Comment: Then what ".load()" are you using...?

Comment: Well,this is the list of js that i use :

<script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
 <script src="js/JakartaWikiMall.js"></script>
 <script src="js/messages.js"></script>

Theres no jquery mobile. Sorry i dont really understand how this worklight work :(

Comment: I think the .load is working because of this single line of code : window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ; :D

Comment: Again, what article are you reading that you decided on using pagePort and .load in your application?