# Worklight WL.Client.init with Windows Phone 8

Tags: backbone.js, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working with Worklight 6.1 and I'm trying to test my application on the Windows Phone 8. Unfortunately I got an obvious behaviour :

Each time I change from page to page, the application call the WL.Client.init function and I got a blank page.

I tried my code on the Android Environment and everything is okay, also I tried to execute my code on the Internet Explorer and it's working fine.

To mention I'm working with BackBone Router to change from page to page, referring to this link : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/backbone-require.html

I'm working with a single page Style : each time I click on on  tag, I delete the content of the page and replace it by an other content with the template principle .

```
<li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
```

and when the user click on the link, The router is triggered the charge the requested template.

```
$page = $(page.el);
        $page.attr('data-role', 'page');
        $('body').append($page);
        page.render();
        var transition = "slide";
        // We wont to slide the first page
        if (this.firstPage) {
            transition = 'none';
            this.firstPage = false;
        }

        $.mobile.changePage($page, {changeHash:false, transition: transition});
```

I made an alert in the main HTML page and I found that in each change page , **the hole page is reloaded** so the backbone router is initialised an so for WL Client .
Any suggestion what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to see the code you use to "change page" in your app, but generally speaking Windows Phone 8 is not easy to handle when it comes to page navigation.

You can take a look at these questions which exhibit a similar issue. Your issue could be with jQuery (which does not play nice with WP8), or more difficult...

- [IBM Worklight - $("#pagePort").load() not working in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491348/ibm-worklight-pageport-load-not-working-in-windows-phone-8)
- [IBM Worklight 6.0 - WL.Client.reloadApp() not working in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792645/ibm-worklight-6-0-wl-client-reloadapp-not-working-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: I'd still try to do the jQuery.js changes based on the linked answers.

Comment: Ok I'll make those changes